Live action, animated cartoon kids show with magic mirror and puppet cat
So, from what I can recall, from Australian ABC TV in the early 90s.
The show starts off in some kind of room, like a children area at a preschool or something. There is a (maybe British) woman sitting (maybe) in a rocking chair. 
Near her, somewhere, is a possibly purple puppet cat? I'm not sure if the cat speaks, but when the kids are all sat on the floor in front of the woman, she begins to tell the particular tale, as she does this, the camera zooms into the mirror where the spectacular 1980s SFX begin. 
Then it leaps into an animation around the story the woman had begun to tell her captive audience. 
One tale was that of the Devils Bridge where the Devil needed a soul or whatnot and needed to convince a human to walk over the bridge, he did this by offering an elderly woodsman a chainsaw instead if his old trusty axe, and something involving maybe...an old woman nearby. 
The other creepy story that has stayed with me was of an old Grandmother in her cottage deep in the woods, and one night a group of tall, very thin/lanky, black furred jackal/werewolf-like creatures came and "broke in" to her home by tearing off the door and pulling the window shutters off the hinges and even tearing the thatched roof off her little house, and stuffed her in a sack. 
I'm not sure what became of the old woman after this point but I need to know what this show may have been. I believe at the end of the tale, the camera returns to the room and the woman tells the kids of the moral of the story or some such nonsense and the show ends. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 

Welcome to M&TV. You've added all the details required. Good. However, if you recall more details, feel free to add it in your question. One more thing, what is shyte?

Was the cat striped purple?

I think you might be thinking of "Romper Room." Romper Room is an American children's television series that ran in the United States from 1953 to 1994 as well as being franchised and aired internationally at various places such as Canada, the United Kingdom, Finland, Japan, Australia, and New Zealand. The program targeted preschoolers (children five years of age or younger) and was created by Bert and Nancy Claster of Claster Television. 
Nancy Claster, the host of the show would start every episode by saying the pledge of allegiance, but only when broadcasted in the U.S., as the show was viewed internationally eventually. She also ended every episode by looking into a magic mirror and look through it to see all the viewers out in “television land.” She would then recite: 

“Romper, bomper, stomper, boo!  Tell me, tell me, tell me do.  Magic Mirror, tell me today, have all my friends had fun at play?”

She would then start naming children that she could "see" through the magic mirror. People could mail their children's names into the show in hopes that their name would be read. If a child had a common name, they had a good chance of having their name read aloud. The famous "Good is great, God is good. Let us thank Him for our food. Amen" prayer is said every episode when the children were given milk and cookies. 
The show then underwent a change in name, "Romper Room and Friends," which included a few new characters as puppets, one of which was "Granny Cat." This might be the cat you are referring to, but it looks like more a bluish color as opposed to purple. This is the Wikipedia page that I found and this is another website that I got information from, as well as other interesting articles on older television shows. I was unable to find anything on the weird scenarios you described, as there is very little online information that I could find. You may want to try renting the series to find out if those were scenes in the show.
